# Same URL for 2 differents pages

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape data from a specific match from the website Sofascore (I use python & Selenium)

I can acess it first going to https://www.sofascore.com/football/2022-05-12 then clicking the match Tottenham - Arsenal with url https://www.sofascore.com/arsenal-tottenham-hotspur/IsR

However, when I enter this link directly from my browser, I arrive to a completely different page for a future match to come.

Is there a way to differentiate the 2 pages to be able to scrape the original match ?
Thanks

Comment: maybe don't `click()` but use `.get(url)`. Selenium has functions to search in HTML and get attribute `href="url"` from link `<a>`

Comment: If I open first and second page in the same browser then I get current match but if I run second page in `private mode` then I get future matches - so all may depends on cookies in browser. It may need to open second page in fresh `Selenium` and it will run it without cookies which you get when you visited first page.

Comment: You might be interested to learn that there's an (unofficial) API. Check the main link for `<a data-id="10236815" ...>`. You'll need that `id`. Now, check your game url in Chrome, open "Chrome DevTools" (`Ctrl + Shift + j`), select "Network" from the navbar, and among the "Names" (below left) you'll find a bunch of endpoints ("incidents","lineups"). Click on one of them, and you'll see the `Request URL` to the right. E.g. use `data = requests.get('https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/10236815/statistics').json()` and you'll have quite some data in JSON.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ouroboros1 All I needed was in your answer, Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I checked the pages you talked about. The first page (https://www.sofascore.com/football/2022-05-12), sends a lot of information to the server.

That's why you get a certain page. If you want to solve this with `requests`, you'll need to record everything it sends with Burp suite or a similar tool.

You're probably better off just opening it with `selenium` and then clicking on the first page and getting the page you want...

If you want to check what the current page is in `selenium`, you can check if the content is what you expect to be on that page...

Jonthan